# PS script runs but doesn't copy over the specified folder

Tags: copy-item

My script run with no errors, but when I verify that it has copied one folder to the next that folder has nothing init, there are files in the source folder.

```
Clear-Host
```

## Get and set varible names

$ComputerName1 = Read-Host "What is the name of your computer?"
$ComputerName2 = Read-Host "What is the name of the computer that has the errors?"

## If folder exists, overwrite it

If(test-path "\$ComputerName2\c$\ProgramData\Micro Focus\"){Remove-item "\$ComputerName2\c$\ProgramData\Micro Focus\"}

## Copy from one computer to the next

Copy-Item -Path "\$ComputerName1\c$\ProgramData\Micro Focus\" "\$ComputerName2\c$\ProgramData\Micro Focus\"

## Delete folder from all users

Remove-Item -path "\$ComputerName2\c$\Users*\AppData\Roaming\Micro Focus\"

Read-Host -Prompt "Micro Focus Fix complete, press Enter to Exit"

Comment: Just to reiterate what I was saying.  My script should copy over a folder, and all of its contents, from computer A to computer B.  If the folder exists on computer B, it should overwrite the folder.  Right now when the script runs, it verifies the path (no issues), deletes the existing folder,  then copies the folder from computer A, but the folder is empty on computer B.  I have verified that there is content in the folder before it copies.  Is there something I am missing?  Running the script on a local computer results in the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Was browsing some questions and saw yours. In case you never figured this out, you need to add the `-recurse` parameter on your `copy-item` command. So:

```
Copy-Item -Path "\$ComputerName1\c$\ProgramData\Micro Focus\" 
"\$ComputerName2\c$\ProgramData\Micro Focus\" -Recurse
```

The `Copy-Item` command will not automatically copy any sub directories associated with the source path. The `-Recurse` parameter tells the command to copy all sub directories, and any items contained in those directories.